Where is best to put power source of LED strips wired in parallel
I have got a 20m length of rgb led strip in which I want to cut and use 10 different lengths for in-between wood on a slatted wall.
I am wiring the strip in parallel. Does it matter where I put the power source e.g middle or start? The length of the cable from start to finish will be around 2 meters with each individual strip being spliced off this cable.

Shortest run between all.

The best option if applicable is to connect positive to the first strip and negative to the last.
This way all current paths are equally long, so the voltage drops along the LED chain cancel out.
In this circuit all segments sink the same amount of current.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The same idea applies to each segment and an even better circuit - where all LEDs sink the same amount of current - looks like this:

simulate this circuit
The current return path will require an additional wire along the LED chain when compared with "ordinary" wiring.
Though, for 2m segments that might not even be neccessary (I don't perceive any deviation in my 2m long WS1812b strips).

thanks for the reply. There is no negative on the strip so I am guessing the rgb are the negative? So run rgb from end of strip to the power source and run positive from start of strip to power source while linking them all in parallel?

@M24 that's correct

Yes, it matters.
One led strip is basically this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here is what's happening if you connect it by one end, as shown in the schematics.
R1 and R8 are the resistances of the cable from the power supply to the led strip (R1) and back (R8). It should be small, but make sure the cable is beefy enough to handle the current of the strip without heating up.
R2 to R7 are modeling the copper traces on the strip. In the real world they are not perfect conductors.
You can see that the voltage across D4 and R12 will be lower than the voltage across D1 and R9. This is because all the voltage drop that occurs because of R2 to R7. There is a long chain made of resistors (here 6) to cross for the current that flow through the D4 branch.
But, if you power it by the middle:

simulate this circuit
Now the LEDs that are at the extremities are much closer to the point where the power supply is connected.
The longest chain of parasitic resistors to cross (R2 to R7) is divided in half.
Therefore, the difference between led current close to the power supply and at the end of the strip is reduced. The led intensities are more homogenous than using the first design. Which is usually better...
You should connect all your strips in parallel, but also connect each strip to the power supply by the middle.
